# Is $f(x) \in \mathbb{R}$ if $x \in \mathbb{R}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f:\Omega\subset\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ be holomorphic with $\Omega$ open. Assume there is an infinite sequence $(x_n)_n$ in $\Omega \cap \mathbb{R}$ that converges to $x_0 \in \Omega \cap \mathbb{R}$ and assume that for every $n$, $f(x_n) \in \mathbb{R}$. Let $D_r$ be the open disk of radius $r>0$ and centre $x_0$ such that $D_r \subseteq \Omega$. Is it true that $f(x) \in \mathbb{R}$ for every $x \in D_r \cap \mathbb{R}$?

I tried proving this by constructing a holomorphic function $g$ such that $g(z)$ is real whenever $z$ is real and $g(x_n)=f(x_n)$. Then by the identity theorem it follows that $g=f$. Unfortunately, I was unable to find such $g$.

Any help would be welcome. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason for $D_r$ to be a part of the problem statement?

Comment: Excuse me, I have edited it.

Comment: I think you mean for every real $x\in D_r;$ it would be good to say that.

Comment: As written, this is clearly false: the identity is a counter example (take any convergent sequence you like, and $x_0 + \frac{ir}{2}$ lies in $D_r$ but not in $\mathbb{R}$. Surely you want some extra conditions on $x$?

Comment: I indeed meant every real $x\in D_r$. I have edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is true for $U_0$ the connected component of $\Omega \cap \mathbb R$ that contains $x_0$

(to show that it may not be true in general even in $\Omega$ connected - assuming, of course, the hypothesis just for the single point $x_0$ as above), one can take the branch of square root that is say positive on $(1,2)$ in a tube that connects $(1,2)$ with $(-2,-1)$ through the upper plane (eg the half annulus $1<|z|<2, \Im z \ge 0$) extended a bit below the real axis at both ends to make it open) and consider $\sqrt z$ which is clearly real on $(1,2)$ but not on $(-1,-2)$)

To show the result we let $A$ the set of points $x \in \Omega \cap \mathbb R$ which have an open neighborhood $V_x \subset \Omega$ for which $f(z) \in \mathbb R, z \in V_x \cap \mathbb R$ and we claim that $A$ is both open and relatively closed (in $\Omega \cap \mathbb R$ of course) while containing $x_0$; trivially $A$ is open by definition, while the proof that $x_0 \in A$ will apply to any limit points of $A$ that are in $\Omega$.

Let $f(z)=\sum a_k(z-x_0)^k$ the Taylor expansion of $f$ on a small neighborhood of $x_0$ and we show that we can take $V_{x_0}$ precisely that by showing that the coefficients $a_n$ are real; since $f(x_0)$ is real as the limit of real numbers, $a_0$ is so; but now $f_1(z)=\frac{f(z)-a_0}{z-x_0}=\sum_{k \ge 0} a_{k+1}(z-x_0)^k$ satisfies the same properties as $f$ since $f_1(x_n)$ is clearly real as the ratio of real numbers for $x_n$ close enough to be in $V_{x_0}$ of course and $f_1(x_n) \to f_1(x_0)$ since $f_1$ is analytic hence continuous, hence $a_1$ is real and clearly we can iterate the procedure so by induction $a_n$ real and we are done (noticing that if $y \in \Omega$ is a limit of point of points in $A$, $y$ definitely satisfies the same hypothesis as $x_0$ hence same proof works to show that it is in $A$)

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation but I have trouble understanding the counterexample. You are saying $\sqrt{z}$ is real on $(1,2)$ but not on $(-1,-2)$, but $(1,2)$ and $(-1,-2)$ do not lie on the real axis. I am looking for a $f:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{C},$, $\Omega$ connected, that is real on some real infinite sequence but not on the whole $\mathbb{R}\cap\Omega$.

Comment: not understand the question - obviously, the intervals $(1,2), (-2,-1)$ lie on the real axis as they are just two open segments there; as noted one can take $\Omega$ an annulus of the type $1<|z|<2, \Im z  > -\epsilon$ for some small $\epsilon >0$ and $f(z)=\sqrt z$ (the branch for which $f(3/2)=\sqrt {3/2} >0$) which is defined and analyitc there

Comment: I haven't seen the theory about principal branch, branch cut etc. Is there maybe another counterexample?

Comment: not sure exactly what you mean here - by taking an antiderivative of $1/z$ that is say $0$ at $3/2$ to fix it uniquely, you get a $g(z), g'(z)=1/z$ on $\Omega$ above (all good since $\Omega$ is simply connected so such exists) and then take $f(z)= e^{g(z)/2}$ which gives essentially the above without considering branches etc; any example needs a function that cannot be defined on the full plane and for which the taylor series is real at some reals and non-real at some reals, so it is conjugate invariant on some piece but not conjugate invariant on another, so it must involve some complications

Comment: comment continued - in particular, note that this reasoning forces any counterexample to be defined on a set that is not conjugate invariant as a whole (as otherwise $f_1(z)=\bar f(\bar z)$ would be defined and anayltic there and equal to $f$ on a piece of the real line hence everywhere), so you are kind of forced to look at analytic functions that have a branch cut, whether you define that explicitly or not

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $g(z) = \frac12\big( f(z) + \overline{f(\overline z)} \big)$. (This is the same construction as in a proof of the Schwarz reflection principle.)

Comment: To define $f$, shouldn't $\Omega$ be stable under complex conjugation? I guess on a small ball around a real point this can be usefull. But there needs to be an accumulation point (which is not supposed in the OP's question)

Comment: I agree, and I think Conrad's answer explores that aspect more thoroughly.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f=u+iv.$ Then $v$ is real analytic on $I=(x_0-r,x_0+r).$ Furthermore $v=0$ on the set $E=\{x_n: x_n\in I\}\cup \{x_0\}.$ Since $E$ is a subset of $I$ with limit point in $I,$ we have $v=0$ on $I$ by the identity principle for real analytic functions. Thus $f(x)$ is real for all $x\in I.$

Answer (score -1):

First of all, $D_r$ seems not to be part of the question or problem?

Secondly: your assumptions is that there exists a particular sequence $(x_n)$ converging to a particular point $x$ and you want to show a general statement that would be "$f(x)$ is real whenever $x$ is real". There is a clear lack of assumptions to show that.

This is the only thing that can be shown with your assumptions:

Let $f : \Omega \to \mathbb{C}$ be continuous. If $x \in \Omega$ is the limit of the sequence $(x_n) \in (\Omega)^{\mathbb{N}}$ and if for every $n$, $f(x_n) \in \mathbb{R}$, then $f(x)\in \mathbb{R}$. This is because $f$ is continuous at $x$ and because $\mathbb{R}$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: I have edited the question.

Comment: I see, this make sense. I still think there is a lack of assumption: I think the sequence $(x_n)$ should be infinite (take a constan or periodic sequence $(x_n)$ and the result is false)

Comment: Yes you are right. I have edited it again.